# RichTextBox font set to all lines in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I changed the font of a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx), but this change does not set to all of its characters properly. Indeed there exist two font for the RichTextBox and that is not beautiful. Is there a solution for this problem!?

This code does not work correctly:

```
this.richTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Maiandra GD", 12);
```

Comment: WPF or winform? What is the type of richTextBox1?

Comment: i use windows form tools

Answer (score 1):

Set the selection to the entire box and set the SelectionFont.

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
this.richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Maiandra GD", 12);
```

Comment: I used this code with a few change
this change is 
this.richTextBox1.SelectionLength = this.richTextBox1.Text.Length; And I Get my Answer Thnx