# C# Use different font size on a line in richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

how do we use different font size on a line in the `RichTextBox`? Let say I want the first word to be font 10 but the second word on the same line I want it to be 20. I'm using the below:

```
    private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox2.Font = new Font("Microsoft San Serif", 12);
        richTextBox2.Text = "\n\n" + textBox10.Text;         
    }
```

But it apply to whole text on the line...

Comment: And what have you tried? Did you even searched for a way to achieve this as I can see a lot of answers to your question in the related questions?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554401/richtextbox-font-set-to-all-lines-in-c-sharp set the selection to the first word change the font, set the selection to the next work change the font etc...

Comment: the example in the website applies to the whole richtextbox..

Comment: Learn about Paragraphs and Runs.  I think that should help you out a bit.  You can use two different Runs in the same Paragraph, but the two different Runs can have different font sizes, etc.

Comment: @froggythefrog He could also just use RTF.

Comment: @AnonymousPi Good to know.  I am still pretty new to the RichTextBox and don't know much about RTF format itself.

Answer (score 1):

What I mean is try something like this:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 10; //End of first word
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10);

richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 11; //Start of second word
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 10;
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 20);

richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 21; //Next section to format
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 10;
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 25);
```

which is just applying what is in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554401/richtextbox-font-set-to-all-lines-in-c-sharp).

Comment: What will happened if the "Tahoma" font will not be present in the client machine?