# c# Winform richtextbox font discrepancy

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

The font property of richtextbox doesn't seem to be working.

```
        // 
        // textBox_rawdata
        // 
        this.textBox_rawdata.DetectUrls = false;
        this.textBox_rawdata.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("NSimSun", 9F);
        this.textBox_rawdata.HideSelection = false;
        this.textBox_rawdata.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(22, 43);
        this.textBox_rawdata.Name = "textBox_rawdata";
        this.textBox_rawdata.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(368, 68);
        this.textBox_rawdata.TabIndex = 2;
        this.textBox_rawdata.Text = "AAAAAA";
```

I want the font of the richtextbox to be NSimSun, 9pt. As you can see in the picture, [image]The first few A's are preset and the last 3 A's are typed in by me. The issues is, the preset characters and any characters generated by the program are correctly displayed as NSimSun, 9pt. But as soon as I start typing in there, the font changes. (Like the last 3 A's)

How can I make the font NSimSun, 9pt for all text?

Comment: Do you set the Font anywhere else? (I'm presuming that code is from a designer.cs file?)

Comment: Yes it is from designer.cs. I did not set the font anywhere else.

Comment: Duplicate. Try this, dude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554401/richtextbox-font-set-to-all-lines-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you.

```
this.textBox_rawdata.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
```

if you want your font type, size and style to be set once you run your code put this in designer:

```
 this.textBox_rawdata.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set SelectionFont property of richtextbox to System.Drawing.Font("NSimSun", 9F) also.

From MSDN it is:

A Font that represents the font to apply to the current text selection or to text entered after the insertion point.