# Formatting text with padding does not line up in C#

Tags: c#, padding

I am fairly new to programming and I just wrote a simple application in C# .NET to retrieve information about system drive space. The program functions fine but I'm struggling with formatting the output.

See output:

[image: Output Example]

I'm trying to use padding to get the text to line up in sort of a column format within a rich text box but the output doesn't line up because if there are multiple drives, the drive names are different lengths which throws off the padding. Even if the drive letter comes back one as M: and the other as I: the difference in the size of the letter is enough to throw off the alignment while padding.

I am wondering if there is a way to force each string value to a specific length so the padding is applied evenly or if maybe there's an even better way to format my output. Thank you in advance for your time and let me know if any further information would be helpful!

Comment: Your problem is [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning). Change your text to a [monospaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface#Monospaced_typefaces) font (where all the characters are the same width) or use a control that has actual columns instead of trying to match up padding. Consolas is the default font in visual studio and is monospaced, for example.

Comment: Try using the Courier New font.

Comment: Looks like its most likely the font you are using, see how much bigger I is than M.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Are you using WPF? Or WinForms? In WPF you can use [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) to display data in a table with columns (which will be properly aligned).

Comment: I am in fact using WinForms. Spot on with the answer. Once I changed the font to a monospaced as recommended, everything lined right up. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** One of the comments asked an important question, regarding whether the question refers to the [`System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` (WinForms)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [`System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` (WPF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) control.  This answer applies *only* to the WinForms version of `RichTextBox`, so if you're using WPF, this doesn't apply.

The most important thing, and this was mentioned in the comments, is that you'll need to use a [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

Since you stated you're using a `RichTextBox`, you'll need to know how to set it to use whatever monospaced font you've chosen.

To do that, you can use the [`RichTextBox.SelectionFont`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont(v=vs.71).aspx) property.

For more general instructions, refer to this MSDN article: [Setting Font Attributes for the Windows Forms RichTextBox Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983722(v=vs.71).aspx)

Once you set the `RichTextBox.SelectionFont` property, only text added to the control *afterwards* will use the specified font.  To apply the font to *existing* text (i.e. you populate the `RichTextBox` and then change the font to an appropriate monospaced font), take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554613/1187982), which tells you precisely what to do.

Once that's done, there remains the simple matter of adding the appropriate amount of whitespace to the end of each string, such that the next piece of data appears at the appropriate position.  You'll probably be using [`String.PadRight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright(v=vs.110).aspx), but for more general information about padding strings, check out this MSDN article: [Padding Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That was an easy fix. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is string formatting example:

```
string varOne = "Line One";
double varTwo = 15/100;

string output= String.Format("{0,-10} {1,5:P1}", varOne, varTwo);

//expected output is
//Line One   15 %
```

where formatting properties in curly brackets are:
{index[,alignment][ :formatString] }

Comment: I was actually looking for this explanation on String.Format as well so thank you very much!