# Why doesn't the string.Format work when the string is set as Text of a Label and displayed in a Panel?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to print a formatted list of contacts in C# using Labels with text that are added to the Controls of a Panel. Everything seems to be working apart from the formatting which ideally would make the data in each row align like in a table, regardless of the length of the name of a person or their email address. The formatted padding is working when printed in the Console but not in the actual WindowForm.

This is my string that I am trying to format:

```
string contactString = string.Format("{0, -50}", allContactsNames[i].InnerText) + string.Format("{0, -15}", "Telephone: ")
                    + string.Format("{0, -30}", allContactsTelNums[i].InnerText) + string.Format("{0, -12}", "Email: ") + string.Format("{0, -60}", allContactsEmails[i].InnerText)
                    + string.Format("{0, 10}", allContactsID[i].InnerText);
```

The outcome in the Console:

```
Agatha K.                                         Telephone:     7466931202                    Email:      aga@tha.com                                                          
Me                                                Telephone:     02013645896                   Email:      dam@w.pl                                                             
Reception                                         Telephone:     102                           Email:      reception@offices.uk
```

The outcome in the Panel:

[image: Contacts not aligning]

I've tried calculating the length of each contact's name and subtracting that from the desired padding so that the total number of characters would be fixed but it didn't work either. What can I do to achieve what's in the Console?

Comment: Display your data in a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview?view=netframework-4.8) or possibly a [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8)...

Comment: BTW, you can merge multiple `string.Format()`s into a single method call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting text with padding does not line up in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401356/formatting-text-with-padding-does-not-line-up-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I used Labels, however the idea of the monospaced font works for both problems. I will also consider using a DataGridView, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code using `string.Format()` works well in the console because your console uses a monospace font - one where every character takes up the same amount of horizontal space.  This isn't the case in your TextBox, so the columns do not appear to align.

You could try switching the font to something like Consolas, but that's really a workaround.

Instead, look at using a slightly more advanced form component like the [ListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=netframework-4.8).